# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value JSON swift

Tags: json, swift, macos

I am so confused because this just stopped working out of no where.  I am not sure if it has to do with my bindings or if they became deprecated or what the deal is but I had no issues previously and I have no values that are nil.  I had it working for a long time and now I keep getting this error on line:

```
self.arrayControllerNames.addObject(names)
```

**Controller.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class Controller: NSObject {

@IBOutlet weak var arrayControllerNames: NSArrayController!

@IBOutlet weak var arrayControllerPrices: NSArrayController!


var names: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var prices: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var descriptions: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var images: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var videos: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var downloads: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


override func awakeFromNib() {





    let url = NSURL(string: "http://url")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data,response,error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data:data!)
            print(swiftyJSON)
            let products = swiftyJSON[].arrayValue

            for product in products{

                let names = product["product_name"].stringValue

                //let prices = product["product_price"].stringValue
                //let descriptions = product["product_description"].stringValue
                //let images = product["product_description"].stringValue
                //let videos = product["product_description"].stringValue
                //let downloads = product["product_description"].stringValue



                  self.arrayControllerNames.addObject(names)

                //self.arrayControllerPrices.addObject(prices)
                //self.arrayControllerPrices.addObject(descriptions)
                //self.arrayControllerPrices.addObject(images)
                //self.arrayControllerPrices.addObject(videos)
                //self.arrayControllerPrices.addObject(downloads)
            }


        } else{
            print("Error")
        }
    }
    task.resume()



}
}
```

Comment: `NSArrayController` does not work at all with multiple arrays as data source. Use a custom class as model. And **DO NOT use `NSMutableArray / NSMutableDictionary` in Swift**. Sue those tutorials which suggest that. Is the array controller connected in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes my array controller is connected in the interface

Answer (score -1):

At least the following is optional:

```
product["product_name"]
```

Probably should use

```
product["product_name"]!
```

instead (depending on your context).

Comment: i tried it and got an error: "Cannot force unwrap value of a non-optional type 'JSON'"

Comment: Can you po product["product_name"] and product["product_name"].stringValue?

Comment: Yes I can but I have been having issues lately.  It seems to not be printing out my results anymore.

Comment: Please do not advise people to force unwrap things, ever. ever. ever!

Comment: @Grimxn, thanks for your input. I was just trying to help. I think I did say "Probably" and "depending on your context".

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but force unwrap is something that only the programmer *with total knowledge* should do. A lot of questioners are not as sophisticated as you - always recommend `if let` or equivalent!